# map markers don't move when zooming in & out of a cloudmade map

Tags: iphone, ios, cloudmade

I am using cloud made map and everything works fine for me.

The only problem I have is that when I zoom in or zoom out of the map, the map markers are not moving with the map.

Source looks like this:

```
id cmTilesource = 
    [[[RMCloudMadeHiResMapSource alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"ABCDEF" styleNumber:78603] autorelease];

[[[RMMapContents alloc] initWithView:mapView tilesource: cmTilesource] autorelease];
```

Comment: put relevant code here :0

Comment: id cmTilesource = [[[RMCloudMadeHiResMapSource alloc] initWithAccessKey:@"f86bcc070043426195347a5b5357964d" styleNumber:78603] autorelease];
    
    [[[RMMapContents alloc] initWithView:mapView tilesource: cmTilesource] autorelease];

Comment: I wouldn't put your (private) API/access key into your comment if I were you, @Arif.  I edited your question to add the source to it.  One problem I see right away is that you are ***not*** assigning anything from your "`RMMapContents`" object creation.  It's a leak!